# Difference between SharePoint Online and SharePoint Offering in Office 365 Platform

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

- Is SharePoint-Online and SharePoint in Office365 platform are same?
  Or are they separate products?
- Is there any APIs available, like WebServices/REST that can be consumed from a SP 2013 On Premises  env., in case if we want to integrate the products available in Office 365 platform with the SP 2013 On Premises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SharePoint Online is part of Office365

For development start at:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-setup-sharepoint-hybrid-cloud-testing/
- https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/wiki
- https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP